# How to restart Jenkins automatically after it crashes or closes?

Tags: jenkins

I am finding a way to restart jenkins service automatically after it fails or crashes, I want to know that is there any way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash scrip in crontab and periodically check:

```
service jenkins status #if installed as service
```

if return value other than correct value then:

```
service jenkins restart
```

But..
in my opinion You should try to find crashing reason. I use Jenkins for years and it never crashed..

Comment: Thanks, the job is in a normal state but just in case if the jenkins crashes. So if I write a script, it should be run all the time, right?

Comment: In crontab You can set how often it should be check, e.g. every 5 minutes looks like this: */5 * * * * You can find more details in http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm To add script to crontab use command crontab -e